# How to pass an array from one view controller to another?

Tags: iphone

I'm developing an application. In it I need to pass an array from one view controller to another view controller.

How can I do this?

Comment: Checkout this it will help you.

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6678097/how-to-pass-the-array-from-one-view-to-another-view-controller][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6678097/how-to-pass-the-array-from-one-view-to-another-view-controller

Comment: [Same question ][1] this is for string.you use it for array.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2228242/how-to-access-string-variable-in-one-view-controller-to-another-view-controller

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do it by defining an array property in second viewcontrollers .h file like:

```
@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController 
@property(nonatomic, strong)NSArray *array;
@end
```

Now in FirstViewconrtoller just pass it

```
SecondViewController *controller = [[SecondViewController alloc]....]
controller.array = yourArray.//the array you want to pass
```

Comment: in firstview controller i got the data to array like array=[[results valueForKey:@"names"]retain].So i use this array in your way.But in second viewcontroller i got the error like Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS” .

Comment: try @property(nonatomic, retain)NSArray *array; instead of assign.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't return directly the reference of the array using `return _theArray;`. It is usually a bad coding design to do so. A better solution to your problem would be:

In your first controller's .h file:

```
@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController
{
    NSArray *_theArray;
}

- (NSArray *)theArray;
```

In your first controller's .m file:

```
- (NSArray *)theArray
{
    return [NSArray arrayWithArray:_theArray];
}
```

And wherever you want in your second controller's code:

```
NSArray *fooArray = [firstControllerReference theArray];
```

Be aware that in this example, the references of the objects stored in `fooArray` are the same as the ones stored in `theArray`. Therefore, if you modify an object in `fooArray`,  it will also be modified in `theArray`.

Answer (score 0):

just declare them in .h file & assign them property nonatomic & retain then synthesize them. Now create object of class & access that array :) very simple :)

Answer (score 0):

In swift you

The first Viewcontroller
in the prepare

```
var yourArray = [String]()
yourArray.append("String Value")
   let testEventAddGroupsViewController = segue.destination as! 
TestEventAddGroupsViewController
        testEventAddGroupsViewController.testEvent = yourArray
```

In the second view controller as a global variable

```
var testEvent = [String]()
```