# Import Arrays in another ViewController

Tags: xcode, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to pass an array from one view controller to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6678097/how-to-pass-an-array-from-one-view-controller-to-another)

I have some arrays in firstViewController that I want to use it in second view controller. Since I am new to XCode I have no idea on how to do it.
I tried creating the object of firstViewController in viewDidLoad method of second view controller. And then I tried

in firstViewController
I created 5 arrays and they both contains data as I NSLogged it.
Now in SecondViewController.h

```
import FirstViewController.h
@property(nonatomic, retain )NSMutablearray *array;
```

SecondViewController.m
    @synthesize array

```
-(void) viewDidLoad
 FirstViewController *importArray = [FirstViewController alloc]init];
 importArray.arrayOfFirstViewController = array;
 NSLog(@"%@", array)
```

but I always get null result.

Comment: Show us some more code such as the interface definitions of your view controllers and the place in the view controllers where you're attempting to set the properties.

Comment: I have edited my question.Please go through

Comment: I think you need to go back and read a C and Objective-C language guide. You're setting the `importArray.arrayOfFirstViewController` to be `array`, so if `array` was nil before, it's still going to be nil after and so is `importArray.arrayOfFirstViewController`. Secondly, why on earth are you creating a new `FirstViewController` like that?

Comment: Array is not nil. I NSLogged it.